# Problem in standard proof of continuity when pre-image is open?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

I have seen several proofs of the fact that a function $f$ from a metric space $X$ to a metric space $Y$ is continuous if every open set on $Y$ has an open inverse image on $X$.

When proving the reverse direction (i.e., "the fact that every open set in $Y$ has an open preimage of function $f$ in $X$ means that $f$ is continuous"), everyone seems to start out with this argument:

For every $p$ $\in$ $X$ and every $\epsilon$ > $0$, the open ball $B_\epsilon(f(p))$ is open in $Y$. Therefore, [various implications] ...

My question is this: it is only guaranteed that there will be an open ball $B_\epsilon(f(p))$ if $Y$ is an open set, but this condition is never imposed on $Y$ (or $X$ for that matter). One could take $Y$ to be $[0,1]$ on the real line, for example, and then if $f(p) = 1$ there will be no open ball around it.

What am I missing here?!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For $Y=[0,1]$, the topology is the topology on $[0,1]$, i.e. the induced topology from the "usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$." That is, the open sets are the sets $[0,1]\cap O$, where $O$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Open balls around $1$ in $[0,1]$ (using the usual Euclidean metric) take the form

$$B_\delta(1) = (1-\delta, 1] \ , \ \ \ \ 0 < \delta < 1$$

And that's because $[0,1] \cap (1-\delta, 1 + \delta) = (1-\delta, 1]$

Comment: $(a,1]$ is an open ball in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an important, and perhaps subtle, point.

If $Y=[0,1]$, then since $Y$ is the whole space, it is always both open and closed. To see that it is open, take any point $y\in Y$. Even if $y$ is $0$ or $1$, any ball around $y$ will be completely contained in $Y$. Why? Because $Y$ is defined as a space in itself, and a ball around $y$ is given as

$B_{\epsilon}(y) = \{z\in Y\ |\ d(z,y)<\epsilon\}.$

Notice the very important part "$z\in Y$". This means that the ball can contain only points from the space itself, and so, any ball around any point in $y$ is still contained in $Y$, and $Y$ is thus open.

Let me know, if this doesn't clear it up.

Comment: This is terrific, @HowDoIMath - thanks so much. Guess I'm so used to thinking of a "range" of a function as being a set within the reals that I forgot to keep in mind that we are focusing on a set **as such**.

Comment: @rasraster Nice to hear :)